# Weird Route Model Binding

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I got this problem in the route with one particular name ("headquarters"): the "show" route has the id parameter in plural, but normally it is in singular.

If I write:

```php
Route::resource('quarters', 'HeadquartersController');
```

executing this command line:

```sh
php artisan route:list
```

I get the parameter in singular as expected:

```php
Route::get('/quarters/{quarter}', 'HeadquartersController@show');
```

But if I write:

```php
Route::resource('headquarters', 'HeadquartersController');
```

executing this command line:

```sh
php artisan route:list
```

I get the parameter in plural:

```php
Route::get('/headquarters/{headquarters}', 'HeadquartersController@show');
```

I solved with this:

```php
Route::resource('headquarters', 'HeadquartersController')->parameters([
'headquarters' => 'headquarter' 
]);
```

But I would like to understand this behaviour, could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, Laravel just uses its own helper Str::singular.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-singular

Which is not perfect and has some exceptions. You can read them here:
https://stillat.com/blog/2017/12/06/laravel-5-string-helpers-getting-the-singular-form-of-a-string-value

> ### singular Special Cases
>
> Any words, or word endings, in the following
>   table will not be affected by the singular method. This is either
>   because the resulting word is already singular, or because there is no
>   inflection available. Word endings are denoted by the prefix *:
>
> The following table lists the words that are not inflected by the
>   singular method. This is either because the resulting word is already
>   singular, or because there are no clear inflection rules available, or
>   they handled separately (see the singular Special cases table).
>
> Amoyese   bison   Borghese    bream breeches  britches    buffalo cantus
>   carp  chassis clippers    code caoitus    Congoese    contretemps corps
>   data  debris  diabetese   djinn eland elk equipment   Faroese
>   flounder  Foochowese  Furniture   gallows
>   Genevese  Genoese Glibertese  graffiti
>   **headquarters**  herpes  hijinks Hottentotese
>   information   innings jackanapes  Kiplingese
>   Kongoese  Lucchese    Luggage mackerel Maltese    *media  mews    moose
>   mumps Nankingese  news    nexus Niasese   Pekingese   Piedmontese pincers
>   Postoiese pliers  Portuguese  proceedings rabies  rice    rhinoceros  salmon
>   Sarawakese    scissors    seabass sea-bass series Shavese shears  siemens
>   species   staff   swine   testes trousers trout   tuna    Vermontese
>   Wenchowese    whitting    wildebeest  Yengeese

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, I also tried with nonexisting words and I got a correct singular, am I correct?  
```php
Route::resource('xxxxxxxs', 'HeadquartersController');  
```
gave me  
```php
Route::get('/xxxxxxxs/{xxxxxxx}', 'HeadquartersController@show');
```

Comment: @Andrea well yes that's possible I don't know all the behavior for every word. My point is that your solution is the correct way to solving it if an exception occurs and headquarters is a known exception.